# Sparql query / accented characters

Tags: regex, sparql

I'm trying to query SPARQL endpoints of open educational resources in order to select resources having in their descriptions a particular string. As I'm working on descriptions in french, I have a problem with a string containing accented characters. For example in this SPARQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o WHERE {
  ?s dc:description ?o. 
  FILTER ( regex(str(?o),"structure de donnée", "i"))
}
```

The é becomes Ã© and then the query doesn't recognize the string in the resources descriptions.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like an encoding problem between the editor and the SPARQL parser. What software are you using?

Comment: I'm writing my queries in this Sparql endpoint: http://semunt.supelec.fr/portal/sparql/

Answer (score 1):

Speaking very roughly:

1. SNORQL GUI sends SPARQL query encoded with the `encodeURIComponent` Javascript function.
2. Sesame SPARQL Endpoint assumes that SPARQL query was encoded with the `escape` Javascript function.
3. Later, SNORQL GUI assumes that its own query was encoded with the `escape` Javascript function.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o2mqngg/). By the way, there is nothing in this endpoint about "structure de donnée", I have write "structure des protéines" instead.

I don't know, how to use this endpoint in a comfortable way. As a workaround, you can write in SNORQL GUI something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?o WHERE {
  ?s dc:description ?o. 
  FILTER ( regex(str(?o), "structure des prot\u00e9ines", "i"))
}
```